# Como retornar um MAP utilizando nativeQuery do JPA?

Tags: java, query, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Preciso consultar um banco que já está criado, populado e é mantido por outra aplicação. Portanto, não tenho as entidades no meu projeto e nem queria criar.

Estou utilizando Spring Boot com JPA. Segue abaixo um exemplo de código:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager manager;

public Map<String, Object> getUsuario(String email, String senha) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("email", email);
    parameters.put("senha", senha);

    Query query = manager.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = :email AND senha = :senha");
    preencherParametros(parameters, query);

    List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = query.getResultList();

    return resultList.get(0);
}
```

Eu queria que o resultado dessa query me retornasse um Map com o nome da coluna e o valor dela. Como fazer isso?